# Is it possible to DRY a section of a responsive angular template without using includes?

Tags: angularjs

I have a small angular app that has a mobile and a desktop view. The client wants the control for each of those views positioned differently in a way that I can't really accomplish with clever use of HTML, as below:

Normal:

[image: Normal View]

Mobile:

[image: Mobile View]

The controls are absolutely identical other than the position, so it feels like a waste to repeat the code. I was going to just plop them in a separate template, but first I wanted to see if I missed some clever directive I can use to accomplish this more easily.

Comment: why don't you use bootstrap ? let's the bootstrap handle your UI

Comment: The above example is actually written in bootstrap. The bootstrap grid does not handle the specific usecase, particularly in conjunction with angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would likely use the flexible box model (`display: flex`) for this. You can find a good overview for that on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Pay particular attention to the `order` property for rearranging your items.

If you're looking for an Angular-specific way of doing this, if you made each of your controls a directive, you could wrap them in a parent directive that would compile the template when it loads.

```
.directive('myTemplate', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var directiveOne = angular.element('<div/>')
                    .attr('directiveOneName', '')
                    .attr('otherAttribute', attributeValue),
                directiveTwo = angular.element('<div/>')
                    .attr('directiveTwoName', '');

            $compile(directiveOne)(scope);
            $compile(directiveTwo)(scope);

            if (/* check window width here */) {
                element.append(directiveTwo);
                element.append(directiveOne);
            } else {
                element.append(directiveOne);
                element.append(directiveTwo);
            }
        },
        restrict: 'AE'
    };
}]);
```

Performance on that approach might not be fantastic, though.

Comment: Hmm, I think I can make that work with a few more changes. Thanks for sharing that link, it's the first time I've seen that feature.

Comment: Glad I could help. Keep in mind, though, that flexbox might not be compatible with legacy browsers. Check out [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for more information about browser support. In light of that, I've also added an option for an Angular-only way of accomplishing this. Best of luck.

Comment: Ouch, that's a pretty long beast. Still, that one solves the issue for me. Many thanks.